# перебирать через цикл все файлы

Tags: android

Здравствуйте, я начинающий программист, и я бы хотел спросить, как можно через цикл перебирать файлы из массива arraylist
Мой код активити:

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity 
  {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setContentView(R.layout.main);
        File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"UsBrauser/");
        file.listFiles();
        ArrayList arr_file=new ArrayList<>();
        int index=arr_file.indexOf(file);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Что конкретно необходимо сделать?

Сначала создаете ArrayList

```
ArrayList filesArray = new ArrayList<>();
```

кладете в него все ваши файлы,

```
filesArray.add(file);
```

затем..

```
for(File f : filesArray){
    //Делаете что-нибудь с этими файлами
}
```

В каждой итерации цикла `for` `f` становится ссылкой на файл из массива файлов `ArrayList filesArray` и вы можете вызывать методы класса File у этого объекта.

Возможно я не правильно понял вопрос (Если это так-напишите)

Comment: timuruktus Мне надо циклом брать каждый файл и его переменоувать в .mp3, а потом писать это обратно в arraylist